# SQL query to get data based on second table's date column

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-8.0

I have two table appointments and evaluation_chart
and looking for the appointment for specific user_ids

but these appointment should have following criteria

1. if evaluation_chart table has a row for any appointment then it should get appointment whose evaluation chart is modified or created latest
2. If no record exists for an appointment in evaluation chart then it should upcoming OR today's appointment.
3. If there is no upcoming appointment then it should get latest appoinment of the past for that user

I have using the following but not getting as expected

```sql
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.user_id,
    a.appt_date,
    a.appt_time,
    COALESCE(ec.updated_at, ec.created_at) AS latest_modified
FROM
    appointments a
LEFT JOIN
    evaluation_chart ec ON ec.appt_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            appt_id,
            MAX(COALESCE(updated_at, created_at)) AS latest_modified
        FROM
            evaluation_chart
        GROUP BY
            appt_id
    ) AS le ON a.id = le.appt_id
WHERE
    a.user_id IN (4, 7)
    AND (
        (ec.id IS NOT NULL AND COALESCE(ec.updated_at, ec.created_at) = le.latest_modified) -- Appointment has an evaluation chart and it has the latest modified evaluation chart
        OR ec.id IS NULL -- Appointment has no evaluation chart
        OR (ec.id IS NOT NULL AND le.latest_modified IS NULL) -- Appointment has an evaluation chart, but no other appointment for the same user has a modified evaluation chart
    )
    AND (
        a.appt_date >= CURDATE() -- Upcoming or today's appointment
        OR a.appt_date = (SELECT MAX(appt_date) FROM appointments WHERE user_id = a.user_id) -- Latest appointment in the past for the user
    )
GROUP BY
    a.id, a.user_id, a.appt_date, a.appt_time, latest_modified
HAVING
    COALESCE(MAX(le.latest_modified), MAX(a.appt_date)) = COALESCE(latest_modified, a.appt_date)
```

I want to get only appointment for each user.

Comment: MySQL version??

Comment: I am using mysql 5.7.33

Comment: i'd suggest using three queries for the three cases and use `union all`.

Comment: Fine, above query can be used to fulfill first criteria using inner join instead of left join. But still I am having an issue with group by as well. When I do group by it gives records that are coming first in list instead of based on last_modified date. Can you suggest how I can overcome this issue

Comment: The inner group by needs to be grouped by user id, that gives you max date per user; from that (max-date, user) pair you join with the evaluation chart to get the id and remaining details. For the other two cases, use not exists to find appointments without evaluation chart entry. PS: All of this could have been much simpler if you were using MariaDB or MySQL 8.

Comment: @SalmanA I have been trying this using mysql 8. but still not able to fulfill my first criteria. can you help on this ? have updated my query as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a greatest-n-per-group problem which needs a special `order by`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        x,
        y,
        z,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY a.user_id
            ORDER BY
               /* 1 */ COALESCE(c.updated_at, c.created_at) DESC,
               /* 2 */ CASE WHEN a.appt_date >= CURRENT_DATE THEN a.appt_date ELSE '9999-12-31' END ASC,
               /* 3 */ a.appt_date DESC
        ) AS rn
    FROM appointments a
    LEFT JOIN evaluation_chart c ON a.id = c.appt_id
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
AND user_id IN (4, 7)
```

Rows are numbered by:

1. chart date descending
2. today or future appointment date ascending
3. appointment date descending